# Need help in making centered form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am noob here, learning new things. I am trying to make this center form.

This is what I have tried so far :-

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    .container {
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%
    }
    
    .center-block {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center fst-italic mt-5">CARD NUMBER CHECKER</h1>
    <br>
    <br>


    <div class="inpCont ">
      <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <label class="col-form-label text-center">Input Number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <input type="text" class="form-control text-center">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-3 mx-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Getting something like this right now, with above code
[image]

Want exactly like this :-

### [image]

Atleast Help me center the input box like an image :)

Comment: It's better if you use the bootstrap class `justify-content-center` on the row provided you move the input inside of it. Like this: https://nimb.ws/c6UiFB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 5 has classes that can do all of that for you as opposed to adding other CSS:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/

`d-flex` sets the container div to a flexbox,  `flex-column` sets the direction of the box to a column, `align-items-center` aligns everything to the horizontal center, and `gap-4` gives you some spacing between all elements. You could even remove the input container all together unless you specifically need it for something else.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center gap-4">
    <h1 class="text-center mt-5">CARD NUMBER CHECKER</h1>
    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <label class="col-form-label text-center">Input Number</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-3 mx-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this look so clean :), Can i format the font also like an result image for Header?

Comment: Yes, see the updated answer. You would need to remove `fst-italic` from your `h1` tag and then add some CSS to override the bootstrap default for the `h1` for whatever font you want. I don't know what that specific font is in your image but if it's not a generic font like Times, Georgia, etc, then you would need to import it (you should use those fonts as fallbacks as well if you want a serif font to display).

Answer (score 1):

this will center it

```
.inpCont {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: That worked, can you tell me how I style the Font on header as well like an image?